deserialize object python.net to c sharp
i am working with the library python.net to embed python in a .net wpf app.
my python module returns a dictionary
points = [Point({"x": x, "y": y, "spatialReference": {"wkid": 25830}}) for x, y in zip(x_coords, y_coords)]
return points

i don't understand how to use that object in c sharp.
var point_collection = pythonScript.InvokeMethod("extractNavPoints", new PyObject[] { FilePath });

the point_collection is a pyObject that contains the dictionary but how do i access that as a c sharp dictionary object?

If you can't find any documentation on pyObject or pythonScript.InvokeMethod, I would try to use an xml or json serialiser on point_collection to find out the structure of the pyObject instance returned, as this might allow you to find where you can retrieve your dictionary from inside the pyObject.
